# QT c++ list of charts

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I am creating dynamic list of charts and pushing them into ui.verticalLayout->addWidget(chartView,Qt::AlignCenter); But as more items i add - than smaller they become, because of fitting to the size of vertical layout. I was trying to find more information about adding to list or smth like that - but didn't realized nothing related with charts. Here is code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        QPieSeries* serie_pie = new QPieSeries();
        double free_serie = 1.33;
        double used_serie = 3.1;


        serie_pie->append("Free", free_serie);
        serie_pie->append("Used", used_serie);

        QChart* chart_for_pie = new QChart();
        chart_for_pie->addSeries(serie_pie);
        chart_for_pie->setMargins(QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0));
        chart_for_pie->legend()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
        QChartView* chartView = new QChartView(chart_for_pie);
        chart_for_pie->setBackgroundVisible(false);
        chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        ui.verticalLayout->addWidget(chartView,Qt::AlignCenter);// add into another place :)

    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: _But as more items i add - than smaller they become, because of fitting to the size of vertical layout._ That's how a `QVBoxLayout` is supposed to work. It first determines minimum required size from its children and requests that size from parent layout/widget. In a later step it layouts its contents to the size it actually got. The got size might be the requested value, or more or less due to other constraints. You may consider to insert a [QScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html) into your widget hierarchy if you want to keep the initial size of your charts.

Answer (score 1):

`QChart` inherits by `QGraphicsWidget`. So you can try to use

1) `QGraphicsWidget::resize(qreal w, qreal h)`

or

2) `QGraphicsWidget::resize(const QSizeF &size)`

And one more for beauty `QGraphicsLayoutItem::setGeometry(const QRectF &rect)`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicswidget.html

If you want to try resize `QChartView`

try it:

1) `QWidget::setMinimumSize(int minw, int minh)`

2) `QWidget::setMaximumSize(int maxw, int maxh)`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMaximumSize-1

Answer (score 0):

Create a [QScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html) and add your charts to that